# Regular Expression of a Specific Word

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regular expression in java using standard libraries that will accommodate the following sentence:

```
12 of 128
```

Obviously the numbers can be anything though... From 1 digit to many

Also, I'm not sure how to accommodate the word "of" but I thought maybe something along the lines of:

```
[\d\sof\s\d]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
(\d+\s+of\s+\d+)
```

This will assume that you want to capture the full block of text as "one group", and there can be one-or-more whitespace characters in between each (if only one space, you can change `\s+` to just `\s`).

If you want to capture the numbers separately, you can try:

```
(\d+)\s+of\s+(\d+)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
\d+\sof\s\d+
```

The relevant change from what you already had is the addition of the two plus signs. That means, that it should match multiple digits but at least one.

Sample: http://regexr.com?32cao

Answer (score 0):

This regexp

```
"\\d+ of \\d+"
```

will match at least one to any number of digits, followed by string " of "  followed by one to any number of digits.